# Setting a time and date and adding to it in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

Basically am trying to set a time and a date in PHP then set a time gap which will range between minutes, loop through between a start time and end time echoing something out for each one. Have tried loads of different ways and cant seem to figure a way to set a date and add to it.

This seems the best script I have modified so far:

```
$minutes = 5;
$endtime = new DateTime('2012-01-01 09:00');
$newendtime = $endtime->format('Y-m-d H:i');

$timedate = new DateTime('2012-01-01 09:00');

while($stamp < $newendtime)
{
$time = new DateTime($timedate);
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes . 'M'));
$timedate = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i');

echo $timedate;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$minutes = 5;
$endtime = new DateTime('2012-01-01 09:00');

//modified the start value to get something _before_ the endtime:
$time = new DateTime('2012-01-01 8:00');
$interval = new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes . 'M');

while($time < $endtime){
   $time->add($interval);
   echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do everything in seconds, and use php's `time()`, `date()`, and `mktime` functions.

In UNIX Time, dates are stored as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

You can render UNIX Timestamps with `date()`.

```
 $time = time(); // gets current time
 $endtime = mktime(0,0,0, 1, 31, 2012); // set jan 31 @ midnight as end time
 $interval = 60 * 5;  // 300 seconds = 5 minutes
 while($time < $endtime){
     $time += $interval;
     echo date("M jS Y h:i:s a",$time) . "<br>"; // echos time as Jan 17th, 2012 1:04:56 pm
 }
```

`date` reference:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php (includes superb date format reference too)

`mktime` reference: https://www.php.net/mktime

`time()` only gets the current time, but just for kicks n' giggles: https://www.php.net/time

And, it's super easy to store in a database!

Comment: Did get it working in seconds but become too complicated for me and found it hard setting up dates, thanks though for your time. Probably more useful if I knew more about PHP, am learning as I go along

Answer (score 0):

This function will let you add date to your existing datetime. This will also preserves HH:MM:SS

```
<?php
function add_date($givendate,$day=0,$mth=0,$yr=0) {
      $cd = strtotime($givendate);
      $newdate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', mktime(date('h',$cd),
    date('i',$cd), date('s',$cd), date('m',$cd)+$mth,
    date('d',$cd)+$day, date('Y',$cd)+$yr));
      return $newdate;
              }

?>
```

Usage:

```
add_date($date,12,0,0);
```

where $date is your date.